# Svelte - pass array element as on:click param by reference and make array reactive

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have an array of objects, each object represents a column (in a table)

I then loop through this array to output the columns.  Each column can display a button which changes one of the properties in the object when clicked.  It does this by passing the column object as a parameter to a function.  The array should be updated and the change reflected in the interface.

The code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let columns = [
        {
            name: 'id',
            sortable: true,
            sortState: '',
        },
        {
            name: 'description',
            sortable: false,
            sortState: '',
        }
    ];

    function onColumnSortClick(column) {
        column.sortState = "asc";
    }
<script>

{#each columns as column}
    <div>
        {column.name} -
        {column.sortState}
        <button on:click={() => { onColumnSortClick(column)}}>-</button>
    </div>
{/each}
```

As you can see, the column.sortState is displayed in the loop and the column object is passed as a parameter to the **onColumnSortClick** function where the **sortState** is changed to 'asc'.  This should update the display of sortState within the loop for that column, but this does not happen.  A console.log of **columns** shows that array is updated however, but the reactive display is not.

If I update the main array from the same function as follows, it works as expected:

```
function onColumnSortClick(column) {
    columns[0].sortState = "asc";
}
```

Is what I am attempting to do possible?

Answer (score 4):

You could simply pass the index of `column` (rather than a reference to `column` itself) to your handler, like so:

```html
{#each columns as column, i}
    <div>
        {column.name} -
        {column.sortState}
        <button on:click={() => { onColumnSortClick(i)}}>-</button>
    </div>
{/each}
```

And then your handler would look like:

```js
function onColumnSortClick(i) {
    columns[i].sortState = "asc";
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I ended up doing in the end, but I wondered if it was possible to pass the whole object instead and manipulate that?  If not, I can live with the passing of the index.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I guess if you really wanted to you could use a writable store and then update it in `onColumnSortClick` with something like: `columns.update(($columns) => $columns.map((col) => col === column ? {name: col.name, sortable: true, sortState: 'asc'} : col))`. Bit lengthy though...

Comment: a bit lengthy as you point out, passing the index is good enough for now :)  Thanks for your insights

Comment: I found the following also works: column.sortState = 'asc';  and then ... columns = columns;  So it looks like a reassignment of the columns array (event to itself) will trigger it's reactivity.